# redux-auth-wrapper redirect not working

Tags: redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I'm using [redux-auth-wrapper](https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper) to handle routing logic for authentication for protected routes. However, it's not redirecting.

My "user" object in the state is of the shape:

```
// state.auth

{
    isAuthenticated: true,
    isLoading: false,
   loadError: null
}
```

Here is my `routes/index.js` file

```
const authenticated = UserAuthWrapper({
    authSelector: state => state.auth,
    predicate: authData => authData.isAuthenticated,
    redirectAction: routerActions.replace,
    // redirects to /login by default
})

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={authenticated(Secret)} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/item_1" component={Item1} />
        <Route path="/item_2" component={Item2}>
            <Route path="/nested_item_2/:id" component={NestedItem2} />
        </Route>
    </Route>
)
```

My `IndexRoute` is a protected component, so when I go to `localhost:3000`, I'm expecting it to redirect me to `/login` but nothing happens. It just stays on the `Secret` component with a null body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the same issue, and found out the solution. You might have found it already as well, but here it goes :

You must have this in your code for the redirection to work :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'

import rootReducer from './reducers.js'

const middleware = routerMiddleware(browserHistory);

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(middleware)
);
```

The third argument passed to `createStore()` is **mandatory**

I found the answer from this [github topic](https://github.com/mjrussell/redux-auth-wrapper/issues/71), feel free to take a look for more details. 
NB: Ctrl+F : "codereviewvideos" to get to the right answer ;)

Hope it helps !

Comment: Yep! That's what I did. Thanks for providing the answer I should have posted